# Como verificar se já existe no bd?

Tags: php

Bom, eu tenho seguinte código:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "vertrigo", "recebecores");


$red = $_GET["red"];
$green = $_GET["green"];
$black = $_GET["black"];


$procura1 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from recebescores where red='$red' AND green='$green' AND black='$black'");
$array1 = mysqli_fetch_array($procura1);


if($array1["red"] == ""){

$inserir1 = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO recebecores (red, green, black) VALUES ('$red', '$green', '$black')"); 

}

?>
```

Pretendo verificar, se já existe no banco de dados, algum registo com esses dados iguais, porém não está a funcionar e ele continua-me a inserir dados iguais.

Como poderia fazer isto com php?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema é que você escreveu nomes de tabelas diferentes, acredito que uma delas nem mesmo exista:

```
//Primeiro comando
"SELECT * from recebescores where red='$red' AND green='$green' AND black='$black"

//Segundo comando
"INSERT INTO recebecores (red, green, black) VALUES ('$red', '$green', '$black')"
```

Percebeu? Na primeira vez você usou a tabela `recebescores` e na segundo vez usou a tabela `recebecores`.

Mesmo que dê certo, recomendo utilizar o `mysqli_affected_rows` ou `mysqli_num_rows`:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "vertrigo", "recebecores");

$red = $_GET["red"];
$green = $_GET["green"];
$black = $_GET["black"];

$procura1 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * from recebecores where red='$red' AND green='$green' AND black='$black'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($procura1) > 0){
    $inserir1 = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO recebecores (red, green, black) VALUES ('$red', '$green', '$black')"); 
}
?>
```

Dê uma olhada na documentação do [mysqli_affected_rows](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.affected-rows.php) e do [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.num-rows.php).

Comment: Você verificou o nome das tabelas? Já conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Consegui! Obrigado, o problema era mesmo no nome das tabelas eu não tinha lido...